# Some JQuery code shortcuts

Tags: jquery

I'm writing a lot of JQuery code recently that seems to repeat itself and I'm wondering if there are any shortcuts for the following:

1) Selecting multiple elements by name, i.e.

```
$("input[type=text][name=one][name=two][name=three]").live(); <-- is that correct syntax
```

2) Multiple live bindings, i.e.

```
$("input[type=text]").live('blur and click',function(){});
```

Thanks

**Edit**:

I've also got this use case, where I want to flip display on multiple elements, I found this on this forum, but I haven't tested it yet.  Here's my impl and I'd welcome feedback on the strategy

```
$("#btn_account_edit").live('click',function(){
    flip_display_on_off(
        $("#btn_account_edit_cancel, #btn_account_save, #account_edit_form"),
        $("#btn_account_edit, #account_edit_static"),
        false,true);
});
$("#btn_account_edit_cancel").live('click',function(){
    flip_display_on_off(
        $("#btn_account_edit_cancel, #btn_account_save, #account_edit_form"),
        $("#btn_account_edit, #account_edit_static"),
        true,false);
});
```

```
function flip_display_on_off($element_set1,$element_set2,flip1,flip2) {
    var display1 = 'block' ? if flip1 : 'none';
    var display2 = 'none' ? if flip2 : 'block';
    for (i =0; i < element_set1.length; i++) {
        $element_set1[i].css('display',display1);
    }
    for (i =0; i < element_set2.length; i++) {
        $element_set2[i].css('display',display2);
     } 
}
```

**Second Edit**:

This is the final version of the code, tested and works perfectly! Thanks to @thecodeparadox

```
$("#btn_account_edit").live('click',function(){
    flip_display_on_off(
        $("#btn_account_edit_cancel, #btn_account_save, #account_edit_form"),
        $("#btn_account_edit, #account_edit_static"),
        true);
});

$("#btn_account_edit_cancel").live('click',function(){
    flip_display_on_off(
        $("#btn_account_edit_cancel, #btn_account_save, #account_edit_form"),
        $("#btn_account_edit, #account_edit_static"),
        false);
});

function flip_display_on_off($element_set1, $element_set2, flip1) {
    $element_set1.css('display', flip1 ? 'block' : 'none');
    $element_set2.css('display', flip1 ? 'none' : 'block'); 
}
```

Comment: `.live` is deprecated as of 1.7. Use `.on` or `.delegate` http://api.jquery.com/live/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Answer to your question : 01**

To select different selector they need to be **separated by comma**, read more about **[jQuery Selectore](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/)**

```
$("#container").on('click', ":text[name=one], :text[name=two], :text[name=three]", function() {

});
```

is correct.

**Answer to your question : 02**

for multiple live event bind event name should be **separated by comma** also. Read more about **[jQuery events](http://api.jquery.com/category/events/)**.

In case of live event binding, we shouldn't use live because its deprecated. Instead of that we need to use **[.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on)**.

```
// here #container is the parent of input[type=text]
// which is already exits in DOM

$("#container").on("blur click", "input[type=text]", function(){

});
```

There is another option for live event delegation called **[.delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate)**. It implement like following:

```
$("#container").delegate("input[type=text]", "blur click", function(){

});
```

**According to comment**

#### Want to send array of input fields as parameter of a function

```
function handlerToInputs(inputParams) {
  var filter = inputParams.join(', ');
  $("#container").on("blur click", filter, function(){

  });
}

// on checkbox click you execute a function with inputs
// if checkbox needs delegate event then
// bind live event like above

$(':checkbox').on('click', function() {
  hadlerToInputs([":text[name=one]", ":text[name=two]", ":text[name=three]"]);
});
```

#### According to Edit

```
$("#some_container").on('click', #btn_account_editfunction(){
    flip_display_on_off(
        $("#btn_account_edit_cancel, #btn_account_save, #account_edit_form"),
        $("#btn_account_edit, #account_edit_static"),
        false,true);
});
$("#some_container").on('click',"#btn_account_edit_cancel", function(){
    flip_display_on_off(
        $("#btn_account_edit_cancel, #btn_account_save, #account_edit_form"),
        $("#btn_account_edit, #account_edit_static"),
        true,false);
});

function flip_display_on_off($element_set1, $element_set2, flip1, flip2) {

    // making flip for first set of elements
    $element_set1.css('display', flip1 ? 'block' : 'none');

    // making flip for second set of elements
    $element_set2.css('display', flip2 ? 'block' : 'none');

}
```

**NOTE** I think you don't need any loopy.

I hope you get all answers.  Happy coding :(

Comment: How about if I want to send an array of different elements.  This is a use case I've just come across 30 seconds ago. I need to send a function an array of elements....as in: $("a[id=one],div[id=two]")

Comment: @SamHammamy send array in unnecessary and confusing, jQuery already have best method for multiple events and selectors. Shouldn't we go for that? Why need to use array/ filter or something like that

Comment: @thecodeparadon The use case is as follows, I'm flipping display:none ? if true : block on a number of elements, so I want to have a function that has the terinary and in some .click() send the array

Comment: @SamHammamy which array to send and you need click on checkbox or radio? but I guess what you want can be implement without array or such stuff

Comment: @thecodeparadon going to try your suggestion to my edit now.  report back shortly

Comment: @thecodeparadon Please find final version of the code in second edit after one fix to your code

Answer (score 2):

The first thing you are trying to do will not work. You can do it reasonably concisely like this:

```
$("input[type=text]").filter("[name=one], [name=two], [name=three]").live();
```

If you have a large number of names, you may be able to do it even more briefly like this:

```
$("input[type=text]").filter(function() {
    return $.inArray(["one", "two", "three"], $(this).attr("name")) !== -1;
}).live();
```

For the second thing, you can do this:

```
$("input[type=text]").live("blur click", function() {
});
```

Keep in mind that the `live` function is [deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/). It is recommended that you use [`delegate`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

Here is an example with `delegate`:

```
$(document).delegate("input[type=text]", "click", function() {
    if ($.inArray(["one", "two", "three"], $(this).attr("name")) !== -1) {
        // handle the event here
    }
});
```

Comment: I didnt get the idea of filter +1

Comment: I think your filter answers part of my second question, which is multiple different types of elements, as in: $("a[id=one],span[id=two]"), I need to sent that array of elements as a param to a function

Answer (score 1):

As for #2, you don't need the word `and` in there. jQuery binding can take multiple events, just space delimited.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use a function to filter the inputs:

```
$( 'input:text' ).filter(function () { 
    return /one|two|three/.test( this.name ); 
})
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/rhKBy/